# Is there a way to output/export/debug an EhCache configuration?

Tags: ehcache

We are trying to debug some issues with EhCache and we are unsure what configuration is being used. Is there a way to export or advice on debugging an EhCache configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output the full Ehcache configuration using a little bit of Java code. Just get a reference to your active cache manager by name. (The name should be in your ehcache.xml)

```
CacheManager mgr = CacheManager.getCacheManager("my-cache-manager");
System.out.println(mgr.getActiveConfigurationText());
```

This will output the current configuration to the log/console.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't known about the active configuration.